# Add average smooth numbers inside an array of numbers

Tags: google-apps-script, arraylist, numbers, smoothing

Need google app script to smoothen an aaray of  numbers with adding extra  smoothining numbers with multiple factors in that array by using for loop. Example suppose the array is- myarray = ["1", "4"," 2", "1","5"," 2"]; and the multiple factor is 1 then the smoothening array of numbers should be as - (1),2,3,(4),,3,(2),(1),2,3,4,(5),4,3,(2). In the new array the numbers in bracket are the numbers as in myarray[] and the numbers not within bracket are smoothening numbers need to be add in the new smoothening array. The logic is every recent item is divided by multiple factor and should add to the previous item with the quotient till <= to the recent item. Like In myarray[] suppose the multiple factor is 2 then the new array should be -(1), 3,(4),(2),(1),3,(5),3,(2). Here the second recent item in myarray[] is 4, so 4 is divided by multiple factor 2 and the quotient 2 is add with previous item 1 in my array[] till <= to recent item and do so in sequence so that the new array made with adding smoothening numbers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Smoothy

```
function smoooth() {
  const arr = [1, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2];//original array
  const sa = [];
  arr.forEach((v, i, a) => {
    let incr = a[i + 1] > v ? 1 : -1;
    let n = Math.abs(a[i + 1] - v) - 1;
    sa.push(v);
    if (!isNaN(n)) {
      [...Array.from(new Array(n).keys())].forEach(x => {
        sa.push(sa[sa.length - 1] + incr);
      });
    }
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(sa));
  return sa;
}
```

Comment: Sir suppose the result new smooth array should be like  (1),2,2,3,3,3,(4),4,4,4,,3,3,3,(2),2,(1),2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,(5),5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,(2),2  instead of  (1),2,3,(4),3,(2),(1),2,3,4,(5),4,3,(2), then what the  code should be bcz i think it would make more smoothening the numbers like step wise ( the number 2 should be 2,2 and 3 as 3,3,3 and 4 as 4,4,4,4).

Comment: I think this is a slippery slope.  I can keep answering these off of the wall questions for you but it neither provides me with a greater understand of what you are trying to accomplish nor does it provide you with the ability to solve you own problem.  Instead I'd recommend that you write a question that truly explains to end result that you wish to accomplish and just a little of the reasoning behind it.  Data smooth is usually done remove noise from real data but too much smoothing also remove real signal and so it can greatly effect the end result.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion sir, i agree with you. When i push values in array then forEach loop give error of array length, can you please help me regarding this sir?

Comment: Before I can help you I need to know what you are tryig to accomplish,  But of course the problem is that your question may take us beyond the scope of this forum

Comment: Thanks in advance sir,  for your kind information i like to use it in my stock indicator for smoothening effect..  Sir my question is not beneficial only for me . your goodself as a wise and vast knowledge in scripting language, may help all who visit this page. Any how, your goodself solve my problem, thats much.